# How do I convert any string, number, or object into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, object, type-conversion

Say, for instance, I load something with `simplexml_load_file()` but I want the output
to be an array instead of an object.

Or, say I have a dynamic value that will sometimes be a string, other times an array, 
and other times an object (ie I don't know what the input will be, but I want the output
to always be an array, no matter what).

What's the best way to ensure any value I have is given back to me as an array?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best method I've seen yet.

```
/**
 * Convert any string, number, object, etc, to an array.
 *
 * @param (mixed) $input
 *  The value to be converted into an array.
 *
 * @return (array)
 *   The original input as an array. If the input value is an empty string or empty
 *   array, the return value will be an empty array.
 */
function arrayify($input) {
  // Zero means empty, so make sure not to include actual zeros as being "empty"
  // since the desired output might be array(0)
  if (empty($input) && $input !== 0) {
    // Empty in, empty (array) out.
    return array();
  }
  return unserialize(serialize(json_decode(json_encode((array) $input), 1)));
}
```

I wish they'd make it (or a derivative thereof) a core PHP function, but since I don't
think that's very likely I figured I'd at least share it on here. Any feedback or
improvements are welcome (assuming that's not against the rules). ;)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use json_decode and foreach loop

```
$result = json_decode(XXX);
foreach ($result as $data) {
  echo $data->arr1;
  echo $data->arr1->arr2;
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah but `$data->arr1` is not an array... Still an object.

Answer (score 0):

For more modern PHP versions you can also use

```
(array) $random
```

This works with null, numeric and string values making them an array, and already array values (does not touch them). For example:

```
$random = "abc";
foreach( (array) $random as $x) {
  var_dump($x);
}
```